# boto3 can not find the config profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

my boto3 setup works with providing the credentials through `/.aws/credentials` - how ever I would like to pass that as environmental variable to work through docker.

this is the content of `/.aws/credentials`

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ABCD123
aws_secret_access_key = BCDSA123

[testing]
source_profile = default
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123:role/access-db
```

everything works - but if I make a setup env variable in a `aws.env` file

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="ABCD123"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="BCDSA123"
export AWS_ROLE_SESSION_NAME="default"
export AWS_PROFILE="testing"
export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE="testing"
export AWS_ROLE_ARN="arn:aws:iam::123:role/access-db"
```

I get the following error

```
root@64813e0cc755:/rate_prediction# python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name = 'testing')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 34, in setup_default_session
    DEFAULT_SESSION = Session(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 80, in __init__
    self._setup_loader()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 120, in _setup_loader
    self._loader = self._session.get_component('data_loader')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 685, in get_component
    return self._components.get_component(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 924, in get_component
    self._components[name] = factory()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 158, in <lambda>
    lambda:  create_loader(self.get_config_variable('data_path')))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 241, in get_config_variable
    logical_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 293, in get_config_variable
    return provider.provide()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 390, in provide
    value = provider.provide()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 451, in provide
    scoped_config = self._session.get_scoped_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 340, in get_scoped_config
    raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name)
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (testing) could not be found
```

and here is my python script

```
import boto3
import os

boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name = 'testing')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('ds-models-testing')
```

which I am expecting to work with - again, seem there is sth missing from my environmental variable and boto is searching for a config file `botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (testing) could not be foun`

Comment: I think the profile should be called: `[profile testing]`, not just `[testing]`. Could you check with that?

Comment: Running as two different users and the location of `~/.aws/credentials` is different for each user.

Comment: @Marcin - thanks - but no - just the error changes to botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (profile testing) could not be foun

Comment: @jarmod what exactly do you mean ? I am just trying to replace ~/.aws/credentials with env variables - that's it

Comment: Do the AWS docs support this (the usage of `aws.env`) ?

Comment: @user702846 You should look into [Using an IAM role in the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html). It explains how to set up cross-account access and which file should be updated.

Comment: Your code explicitly sets `profile_name = 'testing'`. Why are you doing this if you want boto3 to use environment variables as the source of your AWS credentials?

Answer (score 2):

You need to unset the AWS_PROFILE env var.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have config file. config and credentials file should be in ~/.aws folder.

.aws/credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ABCD123
aws_secret_access_key = BCDSA123
```

and in config file .aws/config

```
[profile testing]
source_profile = default
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123:role/access-db
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to pass everything through env variable  !

Comment: please add config file and try with your env variables. let me know if you get same error again.

Comment: the point is to not use any cofig / credentials file - as I have stated in my question. Thanks again.

Comment: if you don't want to use any config/credentials file, then unset AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE, AWS_PROFILE env variables.

Comment: what do you mean by unset ? I already have set to 'testing'

Comment: in linux, if you want to remove env variable, then have to use `unset` command.Just remove both env variable and test.

Comment: set AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should remove this line if you are trying to read from environment variables:

```
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name = 'testing')
```

Documentation says

> The order in which Boto3 searches for credentials is:
>
> ```
> 1. Passing credentials as parameters in the boto.client() method
> 2. Passing credentials as parameters when creating a Session object
> 3. Environment variables
> 4. Shared credential file (~/.aws/credentials)
> 5. AWS config file (~/.aws/config)
> 6. Assume Role provider
> 7. Boto2 config file (/etc/boto.cfg and ~/.boto)
> 8. Instance metadata service on an Amazon EC2 instance that has an IAM role configured.
> ```

Reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html

So as you suspect, most likely the environment variables are not getting set as you expect.  Try adding code to log the value of an environment variable that you are setting via the app.env file just to be sure you actually see it set and can read it as an environment variable:

```
os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'It is not set!')
```

Assuming it is actually reading the environment variables you are setting in aws.env, then try exporting only these 2 environment variables in your aws.env and removing the others:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="ABCD123"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="BCDSA123"
```

Comment: Thanks @Shawn - how about the role_arn variable ? should I set that along with the AWS_ACCESS/SECRET?